# Banco de dados - Imagens

Tags: banco-de-dados, react-native

Estou com muita dúvida a respeito de um banco de dados que armazena imagens e vídeos... Gostaria de saber se existe um banco de dados feito para somente armazenar imagens, ou eu posso armazenar fotos em um banco de dados normal?

Estou criando um aplicativo mobile com o React Native, e o app armazena imagens dos usuários.

Bom, obrigado!!!

Comment: queres armazenar no cliente ou servidor?

Comment: Estudei um pouco sobre cliente-servidor porém não entendi muito, pode me explicar resumidamente sobre eles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite, Desconheço react-native, Porém o que conheço sobre armazenamento de imagens no banco de dados, Daria para armazena-las transformando-as em Base64 depende da linguagem o método para fazer isso... esse link ensina um método direto pelo BD vale a pena dar uma análisada: http://www.lennonramos.com/2014/09/converter-stringimagem-para-base64-no.html

Há quem arrisque gravar o endereço da imagem, mas esse método acredito ser arriscado pois pode haver dependendo do servidor bloqueio do diretorio, permissão, ou até mesmo vir a mudar o diretório.

Sobre os videos, não seria recomendado salvar em BD devido ao tamanho dos arquivos de video que são sempre muito grandes e mandaria o desempenho do BD para longe.